# Mapbox-GL GEOjsonSource vs Datasource

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

confused by the API on mapbox-gl-js.

You can add a geojson file by using [GEOjsonsource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-geojson) or [DataSource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#GeoJSONSource), what is the difference ? It seems like you can only associate a [style](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#) with a Datasource, not a GeoJsonsource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the links in your question ("[GEOjsonsource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-geojson)" and "[DataSource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#GeoJSONSource)") describe to the same domain object, `GeoJSONSource`.

The [first link](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-geojson) is to the Mapbox GL Style Specification, which explains how to declare a GeoJSON source in a style. A style is a JSON file that describes how your map should look.

The [second link](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#GeoJSONSource) is to the Mapbox GL JS API Documentation, which explains how to use the `GeoJSONSource` class in Mapbox GL JS. Your declaration in the style is used to create an instance of `GeoJSONSource`. You can also create an instance of `GeoJSONSource` directly.

You may find [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/) to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. What confused me is that you can add the Geojson via addSource and addGeoJsonSource, whereas you can only add a vector tile source via add Source.  But I guess most users will use mapbox default vector tile source and custom geojson, hence the shortcut addGeoJsonSource.